# "Green" Hosting Solution for ASP.NET

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, asp.net-mvc

I have a client that wants to host their site with a "green" hosting service. I am building the site with ASP.NET MVC and SqlExpress. I've looked around and found a few wind-power solutions, etc, but they all support PHP/MySql or other non-M$ frameworks.

Has anyone found a green host that they like working with? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you'll have to determine where in the world their datacenter(s) are. Consider that some areas of the world burn coal, whereas some others use hydro generated electricity.

Consider:

- [ZenuTech in Quebec](http://www.zenutech.com/company/green-web-hosting/)
- [RackForce in British Columbia](http://www.rackforce.com/dynamic_green_it.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are we allowed to promote our own companies? My company uses solar power. But our data centers don't run 100% off of them. Does that count?

Answer (score 0):

Any new ideas on this, looking for a "GREEN" host. I see a lot of 100% wind powered or some other alternative energy hosts, but nothing that supports .NET and SQL Server 2005/2008.

Anyone have any fresh input on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing - here is what I've found so far:

www.aiso.net/general-hosting-plans.html

www.ipower.com/ipower/web-hosting/windows-pro-plan.bml

Answer (score 0):

[Greenqloud](http://www.greenqloud.com/) offers geothermal-powered (e.g. no carbon offsets but true renewable energy), Amazon EC3 & S3 compatible cloud computing services with competitive pricing. Windows hosts also available.